# Calculating in sub Queries based on multiple Items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Sql Server 2008

I have a couple of Stock tables, with Data As below

INWARD:

```
 Item_ID    Barcode ITEM_CODE   Cp_Id   whLocId dt_added    COLOUR_ID   MRN_NO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 123456 222222  62626262    1   78  2014-10-31 23:04:02.920 2   99897
 123456 222222  62626262    1   78  2014-10-30 23:04:11.340 2   99897
 123456 222222  62626262    1   78  2014-07-23 23:04:16.273 2   99897
 123456 222222  62626262    1   78  2014-10-21 23:04:19.327 2   99897
 123456 222222  1234         1  74  2014-11-01 00:16:42.783 1   99897
 123456 222222  1234         1  74  2014-10-24 00:16:53.447 1   99897
 123456 222222  1234         1  74  2014-10-23 00:16:55.467 1   99897
 123456 222222  1234         1  74  2014-10-23 00:17:00.283 2   99897
 123456 222222  1234         1  74  2014-10-23 00:17:02.080 2   99897
 123456 222222  1234         1  70  2014-10-23 00:17:10.273 2   99897
 123456 222222  12348        1  70  2014-10-23 00:17:14.080 2   99897
 123456 222222  12348        1  78  2014-10-24 00:18:37.340 2   99897
 123456 222222  62626262    2   78  2014-10-24 00:24:38.977 2   99897
```

OUTWARD:

```
 Item_ID    Barcode ITEM_CODE   Cp_Id   whLocId dt_added    COLOUR_ID   PO_NO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123456    222222  62626262    1   78  2014-10-20 23:04:58.487 2   99897
  123456    222222  62626262    1   78  2014-10-30 23:05:04.863 2   99897
  123456    222222  12348   1   70  2014-10-26 00:17:39.780 2   99897
  123456    222222  12348   1   78  2014-10-26 00:18:19.903 2   99897
```

BLOCK:

```
 Item_ID    Barcode ITEM_CODE   Cp_Id   whLocId dt_added    COLOUR_ID   PO_NO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123456    222222  62626262    1   78  2014-10-31 23:03:43.923 2   99897
  123456    222222  1234    1   74  2014-11-01 00:16:24.490 1   99897
```

I'm Trying to generate a Close Report which will be based in ITEM_CODE,COLOUR_ID etc

I tried below logic but its populating same output for each item.

```
`SELECT
p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
--(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)  group by item_code,whlocid )- (select COUNT(*) from outward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code='62626262' and colour_ID='2' group by item_code,whlocid)as Opening_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) ) as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward ) as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD ) as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
--((select COUNT(*) from inward )-(select COUNT(*) from outward )) as TOTAL_AVAILABLE_STOCK,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) )as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK ) as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
p.cp_id,
p.whLocId,
p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 

left join outward out
on p.item_code=out.item_code
left join block blo
on p.item_code=blo.item_code
group by p.item_code,p.cp_id,p.colour_id,p.whlocid`
```

But its showing the same value for all items.

RESULT:

```
 ITEM_CODE  DAY_INWARD_Stock    TOTAL_INWARD_Stock  DAY_OUTWARD_Stock TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock   DAY_BLOCK_Stock TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock   cp_id   whLocId COLOUR_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    1   13  0   4   1   2   1   74  1
1234    1   13  0   4   1   2   1   70  2
1234    1   13  0   4   1   2   1   74  2
12348   1   13  0   4   1   2   1   70  2
12348   1   13  0   4   1   2   1   78  2
62626262    1   13  0   4   1   2   1   78  2
62626262    1   13  0   4   1   2   2   78  2
```

**This in favour of Machha who is Blocked for 2 Days Hope Question is clear and Formats are fine now**

Thanks

**Tried This but its segregating based in ITEM CODE but not under cp_id,colour_id,whlocid **

```
`SELECT
p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
--(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)  group by item_code,whlocid )- (select COUNT(*) from outward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code='62626262' and colour_ID='2' group by item_code,whlocid)as Opening_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) and item_code=p.item_code ) as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where item_code=p.item_code) as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code=p.item_code ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where item_code=p.item_code ) as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
--((select COUNT(*) from inward )-(select COUNT(*) from outward )) as TOTAL_AVAILABLE_STOCK,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code=p.item_code )as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where item_code=p.item_code) as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
p.cp_id,
p.whLocId,
p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 
left join outward out
on p.item_code=out.item_code
left join block blo
on p.item_code=blo.item_code
group by p.item_code,p.cp_id,p.colour_id,p.whlocid`
```

RESULT:

```
 ITEM_CODE  DAY_INWARD_Stock    TOTAL_INWARD_Stock  DAY_OUTWARD_Stock TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock   DAY_BLOCK_Stock TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock   cp_id   whLocId COLOUR_ID
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234    1   6   0   0   1   1   1   74  1
1234    1   6   0   0   1   1   1   70  2
1234    1   6   0   0   1   1   1   74  2
12348   0   2   0   2   0   0   1   70  2
12348   0   2   0   2   0   0   1   78  2
62626262    0   5   0   2   0   1   1   78  2
62626262    0   5   0   2   0   1   2   78  2


`SELECT
p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)  and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid  )- (select COUNT(*) from outward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid)as Opening_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid ) as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid) as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid) as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
((select COUNT(*) from inward where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid)-(select COUNT(*) from outward where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid  )) as TOTAL_AVAILABLE_STOCK,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid)as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where item_code=p.item_code) as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
p.cp_id,
p.whLocId,
p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 
left join outward out
on p.item_code=out.item_code
left join block blo
on p.item_code=blo.item_code
group by p.item_code,p.cp_id,p.colour_id,p.whlocid`
```

Seems this one is working.. But any other Easy or well performing Approach will be really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT
p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)  and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid  )- (select COUNT(*) from outward where cast(dt_added as DATE)<>CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid)as Opening_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid ) as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from inward where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid) as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid) as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
((select COUNT(*) from inward where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid)-(select COUNT(*) from outward where item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid  )) as TOTAL_AVAILABLE_STOCK,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)and item_code=p.item_code and cp_id=p.cp_id and colour_id=p.colour_id and whlocid=p.whlocid)as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from BLOCK where item_code=p.item_code) as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
p.cp_id,
p.whLocId,
p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 

left join outward out
on p.item_code=out.item_code
left join block blo
on p.item_code=blo.item_code
group by p.item_code,p.cp_id,p.colour_id,p.whlocid`
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is producing the wrong results is that is is performing the counts irrespective of your join conditions. Take a look at this section :

```
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD 
        where cast(dt_added as DATE)=CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
(select COUNT(*) from OUTWARD ) as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
```

This is not going to say "Hey I need to make sure that I map correctly to my item code and color", after all how would it even know, its scope does not reach the main query. On top of that it does not even select those variables. All it knows is its count. So, what needs to be done.

**Step 1:** We need to simplify this query a bit. There really is no need for these crazy selects. Count will ignore null values and we can just start grouping things together properly by the IDs we want.

```
SELECT p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
    COUNT(p.dt_added) as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
    Null as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
    COUNT(out.dt_added ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
    Null as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
    COUNT(blo.dt_added) as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
    Null as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
    p.cp_id,
    p.whLocId,
    p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 
    left join outward out
        on p.item_code=out.item_code
    left join block blo
        on p.item_code=blo.item_code
where cast(p.dt_added as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
    Or (cast(out.dt_added as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
        Or out.dt_added Is Null)
    Or (cast(blo.dt_added as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
        Or blo.dt_added Is Null)
group by p.item_code,p.cp_id,p.colour_id,p.whlocid
```

So note here that I have removed the totals. This is to help make sure that this half of the query works. So how do they get reincluded? 
**Step 2:** This is where we start our subqueries. We do this by adding 3 joins which will represent these new tables. This half of the query will look like this:

```
SELECT p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
    Null as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
    pCount.pRecords as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
    Null as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
    outCount.outRecords as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
    Null as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
    bloCount.bloRecords as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
    p.cp_id,
    p.whLocId,
    p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 
    left join (Select ITEM_CODE, Count(ITEM_CODE) As pRecords 
                  from inward 
                  group by ITEM_CODE) As pCount
        on p.item_code = pCount.item_code
    left join (Select inward.ITEM_CODE, Count(inward.ITEM_CODE) As outRecords 
                  from inward 
                      inner Join outward on inward.ITEM_CODE = outward.ITEM_CODE
                  group by ITEM_CODE) As outCount
        on p.item_code = outCount.item_code
    left join (Select inward.ITEM_CODE, Count(inward.ITEM_CODE) As bloRecords 
                  from inward 
                      inner Join block on inward.ITEM_CODE = block.ITEM_CODE
                  group by ITEM_CODE) As bloCount
        on p.item_code = bloCount.item_code
```

**Note:** I have based these methods thus far on what I think you want to achieve. You may notice that the counts are grouped by the item_code. Also you will notice the inner joins in these sub-queries. That is all based on the assumption that you want these grouped by item_code. If you do not then it is a different query. Also an important thing to note, this actually only groups items by their item_code. I don't know if you notice this but your code only assumes that color_id and the other parameters are the same. Obviously the query needs to be changed if that was not your intention. Anyhow we are now at the final step.

**Step 3:** Time to combine the queries. Assuming both of the above queries produce the results you expect Then it is a simple matter of combining the results. You query in the end should look like this.

```
SELECT p.ITEM_CODE  as ITEM_CODE,
    COUNT(p.dt_added) as DAY_INWARD_Stock,
    pCount.pRecords as 'TOTAL_INWARD_Stock',
    COUNT(out.dt_added ) as DAY_OUTWARD_Stock,
    outCount.outRecords as TOTAL_OUTWARD_Stock,
    COUNT(blo.dt_added) as DAY_BLOCK_Stock,
    bloCount.bloRecords as TOTAL_BLOCK_Stock,
    p.cp_id,
    p.whLocId,
    p.COLOUR_ID
from inward  p 
    left join outward out
        on p.item_code=out.item_code
    left join block blo
        on p.item_code=blo.item_code
    left join (Select ITEM_CODE As inItem_CDE, Count(ITEM_CODE) As pRecords 
                  from inward 
                  group by ITEM_CODE) As pCount
        on p.item_code = pCount.inItem_CDE
    left join (Select inward.ITEM_CODE As outItem_CDE, Count(inward.ITEM_CODE) As outRecords 
                  from inward 
                      inner Join outward on inward.ITEM_CODE = outward.ITEM_CODE
                  group by ITEM_CODE) As outCount
        on p.item_code = outCount.outItem_CDE
    left join (Select inward.ITEM_CODE As bloITEM_CDE, Count(inward.ITEM_CODE) As bloRecords 
                  from inward 
                      inner Join block on inward.ITEM_CODE = block.ITEM_CODE
                  group by ITEM_CODE) As bloCount
        on p.item_code = bloCount.bloITEM_CDE
where cast(p.dt_added as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
    Or (cast(out.dt_added as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
        Or out.dt_added Is Null)
    Or (cast(blo.dt_added as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
        Or blo.dt_added Is Null)
group by p.item_code,p.cp_id,p.colour_id,p.whlocid
```

and that is it. Hopefully all the queries are now correct and give you the results you want.

Comment: Thanks

Getting below error for last Query

    Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
    Ambiguous column name 'ITEM_CODE'.
    Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
    Ambiguous column name 'ITEM_CODE'.

I tried to bound it to inward and pRecords but its not accepting

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Column 'inward.ITEM_CODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Ambiguous column name 'ITEM_CODE'.

Please suggest.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Sorry about not getting to this sooner. anyhow the code should work now. Fixed it by changing the names if ITEM_CODE in the subqueries.